# Formula development assistance please?

Tags: excel

Good Evening,

I have a spread sheet thats tracking chase attempts with clients, in the last phase of the book, i have the below

[image]

As you can see in the box that says response received from letter Yes has been entered and the close file box has been completed automatically with no.

My issue is i cant for the life of me figure out how to get the close file box to say yes when the response received cell says yes. Iv also got the formula to show a - symbol if the response recieved cell has a - entered in it.

Heres the formula i have thus far,

```
=IF(ISBLANK(V6),"",IF(V6="-","-",IF(ISNUMBER(V6),"Yes","No")))
```

If you can help me develop this further so that i get the opposite answer to when yes or no is used id be truly greatful.

thank you

Comment: So, you always want the opposite? i.e. `when yes return no` and `when no return yes`?

Comment: @urdearboy thats exactly correct, if yes then no and if no then yes.

Comment: You can use SWITCH function here

Comment: If you have the option to change from `yes/no` to `true/false` you could just use the `NOT` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the below equations to convert the following expressions:

1. `Yes` to `No`
2. `No` to `Yes`
3. Everything else returns `-`

---

### IF

```
=IF(A1="No","Yes",IF(A1="Yes","No","-"))
```

### SWITCH

```
=IFERROR(SWITCH(B2,"Yes","No","No","Yes"),"-")
```

Comment: This doesnt work, it just shows the - symbol irrespective of if Yes or No is entered.

Comment: AFAIK version 2019 or MS Excel 365 needed for the `SWITCH` function :-)

Comment: @LordSnow I updated with a `IF` statement that does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

enter where it says 'no' in your table (cell c2, going by my example below).

```
             =VLOOKUP(B2,{"yes","no";"no","yes";"-","-"},2,0)
```

you could expand and adapt this to cover other if conditions & multiple arrays . replaces if formulae in effect.

when you dont have the option of referencing other tables or creating helper tables, do that.